# How to allow password protected start-stop-daemon functionality?

Tags: ubuntu, security, encryption, passwords, daemon

I would like to use Ubuntu's `start-stop-daemon` to start my application, but the application protects some sensitive information, so I have a mechanism where the application prompts for a password that's then used to generate a hashkey, which is used as the secret key for a symmetric encryption (AES) to encrypt and decrypt things from a database.

I'd like to daemonize this application and have it run from `start-stop-daemon`, so that `sudo service appname stop` and `sudo service appname start` would work, but, I'm not sure how to go about doing this with the added complexity of a password prompt.

Is there something that supports this or do I have to program it from scratch? I figured I should ask first before re-inventing the wheel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The point of daemons is to run without interaction.  If you run as a true daemon, there will be at some point a system reboot with you not being around.  You can't really prompt at that point.

So, you either not make it a daemon, needing an interactive startup, or you have a file someplace that has the key, and that file is protected by root read only perms.  Or a major rearchitecture, which may make the most sense.

Comment: It should fail if not prompted. So, it doesn't necessarily have to conform to the definition of a 'true daemon.'  Can you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by a major re-architecture? I haven't coded anything, but according to a compliance specification that I'm reading, prompting for a master key is considered an acceptable security measure for generating the symmetric key to decrypt/encrypt.